# Upload to Firebase Storage executes but image comes back as a black square. Tried everything

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, expo

Hey I've been building out a full-stack tinder app using react native + firebase auth/storage/realtimedb.

Everything has been going great so far but I've ran into an issue a few days ago and I don't know what's wrong with it.

I get back the correct uri of the image and pass it in as parameters to my uploadImage function and convert that to a blob. It uploads a file to firebase storage but it's not my image. This is what gets uploaded:

[Image that is getting uploaded.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwoKI.png)

[Weird things going on in the file description of my 'image'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmsIx.png)

The first things I notice is when I upload the image and look at the description of the supposed image I see that the size is 600,000 bytes which is strange because when I upload the pictures manually through the firebase storage console they are a few megabytes.

The second thing is the image preview is not working.

```
editAvi = async () => {
      console.log('wtf')
        await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        const { cancelled, uri } = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          allowsEditing: true,
        });
        if (!cancelled) {
          this.setState({ image: uri });
  }
        console.log('The image is' + this.state.image)
      };
  uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {
    // Create file metadata including the content type
    var metadata = {
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    }
    // Points to the root reference

    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

    // Points to 'images'
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    var ref = storageRef.child('images/' + this.state.currentID);
    ref.put(uri, metadata);
      console.log('This is the blob: ' + blob)
  }
```

I've been researching this extensively for two days and have asked about it multiple times in a web development discord I'm in and I still can't fix it.

Please help me fix this! This is one of the last things I need to get this app done. :)

Comment: I see that you set `contentType` to `var metadata`, but Did you add a data to `var metadata`?

Comment: Okay so the reason I had to add the var metadata is because before, my images kept being uploaded as application/octet-stream which was already a red flag. Not sure what you mean by adding data to the metadata variable. Inside of my metadata var there is a contentType: 'image/jpeg' that fixed the issue with the application/octet-stream

Answer (score 4):

Found this question when I was also searching for an answer. I was able to solve this following the recommendation from a Github issue https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2402#issuecomment-443726662

The main idea is to replace

```
const response = await fetch(uri);
const blob = await response.blob();
var ref = storageRef.child('images/' + this.state.currentID);
ref.put(uri, metadata);
```

with

```
const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = () => {
                resolve(xhr.response);
            };
            xhr.onerror = (e) => {
                reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
            };
            xhr.responseType = "blob";
            xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
            xhr.send(null);
        });
var ref = storageRef.child('images/' + this.state.currentID);
ref.put(blob, metadata);
```

Fetch in know to have a problem in ReacNative when using Expo.

Hope this solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Found this question when I was searching around for a solution to the exact same issue. I fixed it after about 12 hours of trial and error by adding 'application/octet-stream;BASE64' a the type when creating the blob (using rn-fetch-blob).

Blob.build(data, { type: 'application/octet-stream;BASE64' });

Not sure if that's the method you're using to create the blob, but if so, using that as the type fixed the issue for me.